# Converting from long to wide in R -- values not being filled in cells

Tags: r

I've perused through countless posts and could not find a solution to what I'm experiencing. I have some stock data (in long format) that I wish to convert into wide format. I'm using the `cast` function in the `reshape` package, but for some reason, the cells are being filled with `1` and `0` instead of the the adjusted closing prices. This is a sample of my dataset:

```
Ticker    days    Adj.Close
ABC       -100    44
ABC       -99     43
ABC       -98     43.4
ABC       -97     44.3
...       ...     ...
```

When I use `cast(df, Ticker ~ days, value = "Adj.Close")`, I get the right structure, but the cells are filled with `1` and `0` like this:

```
Ticker    -100    -99    -98    -97    ...
ABC         1      0      0      1
DEF         0      0      0      1
GHI         1      1      0      0
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks so much.

Comment: You probably have some cells that you're mapping multiple values to, so it's giving you the length of the values vector. Without a reproducible example, there's no way for us to know. Fyi, the reshape package has been replaced by reshape2, which has been replaced by tidyr. http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: `?cast` tells you that `aggregation function needed if variables do not identify a single observation for each output cell. Defaults to length (with a message) if needed but not specified.` So you have one ticker with more than one closing price for a specific date. You could try: `fun.aggregate=mean` or delete dupes.

Comment: Please review [mcve].  In particular, please cut your problem down the smallest size that still illustrates the problem and display the result of running `dput(DF)` in your question.  The objective is that anyone else can just copy and paste your code and data and see the problem reproduced in their session.

Comment: Also note that normally the columns are time series, not the rows so the column names would be ABC, DEF, etc.